# Not clearly stated in the Help Center - Asking

Tags: discussion

On the [Help Center | Asking](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) page it states:
"Be constructive: name-calling is as likely to drive folks away as it is win them to your cause."

Should this be changed to state that name-calling is more likely to drive folks away than it is to win them to your cause?

Comment: Why? Is there peer-reviewed research on the comparative probabilities?

Comment: My answer is no.

Comment: @TimLymington You pedantic twit! Can't you just use your brain to see that he is obviously right? Are you a shill for the statisticians in the world? Given that you are a masochistic coward, I'll bet you agree with vgoff and me now!

Comment: @bib It's hard to tell, that outburst may have _won me to your cause_.

Comment: It's an opinion, not a fact. There are lots of opinions, stated in lots of ways; you may have noticed that here. I would say worrying about the comparative details on the Help page is more easily classifiable as pedantry than what @Tim said.

Comment: @John: I would suggest that bib's comment was an attempt at the  scientific research in question rather than his own opinion. As such, I asked for it.

Comment: If we're going to take issue with that particular clause (or whatever pedantic twat wrote it), I want to go on record as saying I have more of an issue with it being plural ***folks***. I'm not saying my preference for singular ***folk*** is *that* big a deal for me, but relatively speaking I care about it more than OP's bugbear.

Comment: Great, now I have to go look up bugbear.  Oh, why didn't you just say bugaboo?